# Where can I find small2e.tex and sample2e.tex in the MacTex installation?

Tags: installing, mactex

I cannot seem to find these files. I am trying to learn LaTeX again many years after I stopped using it on a regular basis, and wanted to start with these files as a reference.

I have searched with 'find' as well as looking online to see if they are available on a website, but have not yet been able to find them.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) Both can also be found on CTAN: `sample2e.tex` is available through ftp://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/sample2e.tex and `small2e.tex` through ftp://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/small2e.tex

Comment: @PeterJansson more correctly: `mirror.ctan.org` (no `tex-archive`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should have a command line tool called `kpsewhere` that searches the texmf tree. Therefore by

```
kpsewhere sample2e.tex
```

it should output the path to `sample2e.tex`.

Comment: for me it was kpsewhich

Comment: Note that `kpsewhere` is a script that basically calls `kpsewhich`.

Answer (score 5):

They should be in the core latex distribution so you should be able to go from anywhere

```
pdflatex sample2e
```

and the file should latex then `sample2e.log` should show the directory where it is located.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this at [CTAN website](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base), under *macros/latex/base*